# elasticsearch server 7.1 is not running

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch version 7.2 i want to use it in production mode for that i did some changes in its `elasticsearch.yml` file such as

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.1.8"]
```

by following these links 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/discovery-settings.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_discovery_changes

when i run elasticsearch server it throws two error messages

```
[2019-07-09T18:07:04,978][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2019-07-09T18:07:05,759][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,418][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] initialized
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,419][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] starting ...
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,525][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] publish_address {192.168.1.8:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,531][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,568][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] stopping ...
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,579][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] stopped
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,580][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] closing ...
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,594][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] closed
[2019-07-09T18:07:06,596][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [sara-Inspiron-7773] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

i did add

```
elasticsearch    -       nofile          65535
```

in `/etc/security/limits.conf` file as given in 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#limits.conf
for error [1] in the logs but i did not resolved the issue
i tried logging in again and run the elasticsearch server but it did not helped

Comment: `/etc/security/limits.conf` is applied on boot. Did you reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run `ulimit -n unlimited` to use the value from `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

**If it does not work**

Check the hard limit for the number of file descriptor: `ulimit -Hn`. If it is below 65536 you won't be able to increase the soft limit. To increase the hard limit connect as root and run `ulimit -Hn 65536`.

Using elasticsearch user set the soft limit to 65536 using `ulimit -Sn 65536`

Restart elasticsearch.

**Still does not work ?**

Check in .bashrc file and other similar file if the limit is not set elsewhere.

You can read [this article](http://geekswing.com/geek/quickie-tutorial-ulimit-soft-limits-hard-limits-soft-stack-hard-stack/) for details about soft/hard limits.

Comment: i logged in as a root then ulimit -n returns 1024 and and then i did ulimit -n 65530 and again checked that by ulimit -n returned 65530 and ran elasticsearch server it gives  the same error message as i mentioned above in the logs

Comment: I have updated the response with a more detailed solution.

Comment: what is the meaning of "Using elasticsearch use" i did not have any elasticsearch user

Comment: If you don't have an elasticsearch user, use the user who start elasticsearch. If you are using a service, you probably have an elasticsearch user. Check the `elasticsearch.service` file.

Comment: the user who start the elasticsearch named sara do added sara             -       nofile          65535 and booted again but the problem persists